# Decoding ARM vmov r2,r3,d0 and vmov d0,r1,r2 - official docs anyone?

Tags: arm

I'm writing a disassembler which is 95% complete but can't find the bitwise layouts for a couple of instructions. I have built them using both as/ld and FASMARM and they work fine on an ancient RPi emulator under "-mfpu=vfpv2 -mfloat-abi=hard".

```
vmov r2,r3,d0 -> EC532B10h == 0b1110_1100_0101_0011_0010_1011_0001_0000
vmov d0,r1,r2 -> EC421B10h == 0b1110_1100_0100_0010_0001_1011_0001_0000
```

I assume they behave as (FMRDH+FMRDL) and (FMDHR+FMDLR) rolled into one respectively.

I could of course take a blind stab and invent new (pre-UAL style) names, but...

Answer (score 0):

As always, sigh, right in front of me face..

fmdrr https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0301/h/vfp-programmer-s-model/armv5te-coprocessor-extensions/fmdrr?lang=en

fmrrd https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0301/h/vfp-programmer-s-model/armv5te-coprocessor-extensions/fmrrd

They are indeed missing from DDI 0100E, but that's no excuse!